# How can I groupby on one column while sorting by another over the entire dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
   id    total
   1     50
   1     0
   1     0
   2     100
   2     0
   2     0
   3     75
   3     0
   3     0
```

But I need it to sort by the **total** in descending order, while keeping the rows grouped by **id**. Like this:

```
   id    total
   2     100
   2     0
   2     0
   3     75
   3     0
   3     0
   1     50
   1     0
   1     0
```

I've tried some suggestions using groupby like this:

```
grouped = df.groupby('id').apply(lambda g: g.sort_values('total', ascending=False))
```

It looks like what it's doing is grouping and sorting the **id** in ascending order and then sub-sorting the **total** within each grouped **id**. But I need it to sort all the rows in the **total** while keeping the rows grouped by **id**

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't make sense. What if you've value `25` in `id` 2. Can you make a [mcve] which covers all edge cases?

Comment: @Ch3steR  See my interpretation of OP's intended requirement in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do this by `cummax()` method,`sort_values()` method and `loc` accessor:

```
df=df.loc[df.cummax().sort_values('id',ascending=False).index]
```

**OR**

Via `groupby()` and `assign()` method:

```
df=df.assign(order=df.groupby('id').cummax()).sort_values('order',ascending=False).drop('order',1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach using `.groupby()`, `.list()`, and `.explode()`

```
>>> df
   id  total
0   1     50
1   1      0
2   1      0
3   2    100
4   2      0
5   2      0
6   3     75
7   3      0
8   3      0
>>> df.sort_values('total', ascending=False).groupby('id', sort=False).agg(list).explode('total').reset_index()
   id total
0   2   100
1   2     0
2   2     0
3   3    75
4   3     0
5   3     0
6   1    50
7   1     0
8   1     0
```

The idea starts by sorting the `total` column in descending order. Then, grouping it by `id` column without sorting the grouping index. Next, passing the `list()` function to `.agg()` as a parameter. Finally, use `.explode()` on `total` column.

Answer (score 1):

#### (1) Clarification of requirement

First of all, let's revisit/clarify your requirement by exploring the expected result for a more complicated data sample:

```
   id  total
0   1    100
1   1     70
2   1     68
3   1     65
4   2    100
5   2     80
6   2     50
7   3    100
8   3     75
9   3     70
```

According to the main point of your requirement:

> **I need it to sort all the rows in the total while keeping the rows**
> **grouped by id**

I would interpret it as requiring row by row comparison of the largest element in a group with the largest element of another group, if there is a tie (same value), we go on comparing the 2nd largest element of every group, and so on. This will be like the lexical ordering of a word dictionary, but in reverse order.

For this interpretation, I would expect the sorted outcome to be:

```
   id  total
0   2    100
1   2     80
2   2     50
3   3    100
4   3     75
5   3     70
6   1    100
7   1     70
8   1     68
9   1     65
```

Here, although the last group in the sorted result (with `id` `1`) has one more element and the total sum of the group is the largest among all groups, it is still sorted at the last since it has the first largest element ties with those of other 2 groups while its second largest element is the least among the 2nd largest elements of all groups. Hence, sorted at the last.

#### (2) Approaching the solution

To ensure the solution works for the sample data presented in any order, let's sort the data first.  You can freely skip this step if your data of `total` column are already sorted in descending order.

Let's use your sample data (but **shuffled** in row ordering):

```
   id  total
0   3      0
1   3     75
2   2    100
3   2      0
4   1      0
5   1      0
6   1     50
7   2      0
8   3      0
```

Then, sort it according to your ordering:

```
df1 = df.sort_values(['id', 'total'], ascending=[True, False])

   id  total
6   1     50
4   1      0
5   1      0
2   2    100
3   2      0
7   2      0
1   3     75
0   3      0
8   3      0
```

**Applying the solution to your sample data:**

```
df_sorted = (df1.set_index('id')
                .loc[
                    np.argsort(df1.groupby('id')['total'].agg(list))
                    .sort_values(ascending=False)
                    .index
                    ]
            ).reset_index()

print(df_sorted)


   id  total
0   2    100
1   2      0
2   2      0
3   3     75
4   3      0
5   3      0
6   1     50
7   1      0
8   1      0
```

This is your expected outcome.

**Applying the solution to the more complicated data:**

Let's have the complicated data also shuffled:

```
   id  total
0   1     65
1   1     70
2   2    100
3   2     50
4   3    100
5   3     75
6   1     68
7   1    100
8   2     80
9   3     70
```

Then, sort it according to your ordering:

```
df1 = df.sort_values(['id', 'total'], ascending=[True, False])

   id  total
7   1    100
1   1     70
6   1     68
0   1     65
2   2    100
8   2     80
3   2     50
4   3    100
5   3     75
9   3     70
```

Then, apply the solution:

```
df_sorted = (df1.set_index('id')
                .loc[
                    np.argsort(df1.groupby('id')['total'].agg(list))
                    .sort_values(ascending=False)
                    .index
                    ]
            ).reset_index()

print(df_sorted)


   id  total
0   2    100
1   2     80
2   2     50
3   3    100
4   3     75
5   3     70
6   1    100
7   1     70
8   1     68
9   1     65
```

Here, we got the expected outcome shown in the clarification of requirement.

#### (3) Explanation of approach

Let's do an anatomy of steps in detail:

**(1) First of all, we perform a `.groupby()` on `id` and take column `total` to aggregate as lists:**

```
df1.groupby('id')['total'].agg(list)

id
1    [100, 70, 68, 65]
2        [100, 80, 50]
3        [100, 75, 70]
Name: total, dtype: object
```

We got lists for each group with the list entries sorted in descending order.  This sorting sequence was attributed to the sorting step before our main processing.

**(2) Then, we use [`np.argsort()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) on this aggregated series to get `the indices that would sort an array`:**

```
np.argsort(df1.groupby('id')['total'].agg(list))


id
1    0
2    2
3    1
Name: total, dtype: int64
```

With the help of [`np.argsort()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html), we obtained the sequencing that would sort the lists in last step.  As we want to get the groups sorted in **descending order**, we further sort this outcome in descending order as follows:

```
np.argsort(df1.groupby('id')['total'].agg(list)).sort_values(ascending=False)


id
2    2
3    1
1    0
Name: total, dtype: int64
```

Now, we already arrived at **the correct sequencing of the groups** with the `id` sequence: `2 3 1`.  The rest of the steps are to take this sequence back to the whole dataframe and display the groups in correct sequence.

**(3) Get back the correct indices sequence for presentation of the whole groups sequencing:**

We get the indices of `id` groups by `.index` and then present to the whole dataframe by:

```
df1.set_index('id').loc[]
```

As the index we got from previous step was the `id` index, we do a `.set_index()` on `id` in order to match the index.  Further with `.loc`, we get:

```
    total
id       
2     100
2      80
2      50
3     100
3      75
3      70
1     100
1      70
1      68
1      65
```

Here `id` is the row index.  To restore `id` from row index to data column, we do a final step of `.reset_index()` to get the final outcome:

```
   id  total
0   2    100
1   2     80
2   2     50
3   3    100
4   3     75
5   3     70
6   1    100
7   1     70
8   1     68
9   1     65
```

Comment: Thank you for putting the time and detail into this great explanation.

Comment: @TheMeanWon  Just curious.  So you want only to compare the largest figure within a group, right ?   You don't want to compare the 2nd largest if the first largest of all groups are the same, right ?

Comment: @TheMeanWon   `cummax()` will only compare the largest within the group.  So you can't compare for the rest (2nd largest, 3rd largest, etc.) if the 1st largest, 2nd largest tie (same values) among all groups.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sort_values, but first reset_index and then set_index:

```py
#simplier aggregation
total_by_id_df = df.groupby(["id"])['total'].sum()
total_by_id_df.reset_index().sort_values(['total']).set_index(['id','total']))
```